Where does anythingLLM desktop save its embedding database files
I have installed anythingLLM desktop (app) on my Windows 11 (Home) platform. I have used ollama (installed in WSL2 Ubuntu) to run LLMs. anythingLLM is running fine. I am unable to find out where its vector database (lancedb) files are stored. And also where the other related files of anythingLLM are saved. I could not find anything either under C:\program files or c:\program files(x86). I am doing a project and my interest it to transform/export stored embeddings in lancedb, to say, in csv format. Thanks.

for windows - C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\anythingllm-desktop\storage

Right click on the icon on desktop (or where it is). Then choose open file location. If it (for some reason) is another shortcut, right click again and choose again open file location. You'll find executable along with other files and folders. From here just start your own inquiry.
